# display: table-header-group not working in chorme while print

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with #css when I print my work from browser chrome.
I want the tag  to show on every page of content.
I set the header variable for the top content of every page.
is *thead {display: table-header-group;}*
but still not working in browser chorme  What should I do? Please help me

my css

```
@media print { table {page-break-after:auto; border: none; } thead {display: table-header-group;}}
```

Comment: What you mean with "not working"?

Comment: @giacomoM It only shows one page. not showing every page